# How to implememnt multi-index search in Algolia - React

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I want to know if there's a way to implement multi index search using React InstantSearch of Algolia , such that it acts as a single query and i get the result in a single hit

I read the Docs and there is a way to perform multi index search like

```
 <Index indexName="instant_search">
     <Hits />
 </Index>

 <Index indexName="instant_search_demo_query_suggestions">
     <Hits />
 </Index>
```

But here the result is returned differently in two different hits , but i want to get the result in the same hit